# asp.net HTMLEDITOREXTENDER ajaxcontroltoolkit lower border not showing

Tags: asp.net

So i have the whole thing working and set up, except that the box of the htmleditorextender has no lower border if I customize the height of the textbox. If I leave it unspecified, it displays correctly but the boxes too big to have in the page. What can I do?

This is the code I have:

```
                           <asp:TextBox

            ID="TServiceDescription"
            TextMode="MultiLine"
            Height="150px"
            BorderWidth="0"
              runat="server" />

            <cc1:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1"
                TargetControlID="TServiceDescription"      
                runat="server" >
                <Toolbar>   
            <ajaxToolkit:Bold />
            <ajaxToolkit:Italic />
            <ajaxToolkit:Underline />
            <ajaxToolkit:StrikeThrough />
            <ajaxToolkit:Subscript />
            <ajaxToolkit:Superscript />
            <ajaxToolkit:JustifyLeft />
            <ajaxToolkit:JustifyCenter />
            <ajaxToolkit:JustifyRight />
            <ajaxToolkit:JustifyFull />
            <ajaxToolkit:InsertOrderedList />
            <ajaxToolkit:InsertUnorderedList />
            <ajaxToolkit:CreateLink />


            <ajaxToolkit:Indent />

        </Toolbar>
        </cc1:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can define Rows for the TextBox control. as

```
        ID="TServiceDescription"
        TextMode="MultiLine"
        rows="10"
        BorderWidth="0"
          runat="server" />
```